# Why is the site layout of scifi.se different from other se sites?

Tags: discussion, design

In all other (at least the ones that I have checked: biology, chemistry, stackoverflow, math, ELU, TeX, Academia and the beta sites) the user profile page follows the new format. When you click your own profile, the default is the activity tab which is missing in [scifi.se]. Also, the layout is still the old format.

I am using a dark gtk theme (Mona 3.0) on an XFCE desktop (fedora-21/22). With other sites the comment boxes and question/answer boxes are insensitive to the theme. But with [scifi.se] the font is white which makes it invisible in white background. There is a fix for this which prevents dark themes to override text-boxes in the websites, which I did implement and the problem is solved. I guess, some CSS implementation makes other se sites insensitive to the gtk theme.

Why is the layout/configuration of [scifi.se] still in the old format? Are we expecting an update soon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other sites all have their updated base CSS. List of sites with and without it is [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed) (hint SFF isn't actually the *only* site without the update).

This is probably what's causing the issue. Fortunately, all sites (other than Area 51) are slated to get updates to their CSS soon... and there's only eight remaining, so, hopefully SFF will get the update and the new user pages soon, which should fix this issue.